# Eclipse not showing my android perspective

Tags: android, eclipse

When I open Eclipse my custom perspective doesn't load even though the tab is selected.
I have to change to debug mode and change back to my perspective. Why would it not load the first time 
[image]

once I click debug it loads fine
[image]
after if i click back to the custom perspective it loads[image]
Why would this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the screenshots it seems like the views in your perspective are minimized. Look at the sides and you will see a toolbar with a restore button. Click on it and the views will be shown again.

As you switch perspective, the layout of the perspective will be changed. So you should typically only have to restore the views once and it will be remembered.